# How to add AWS Lambda function as an authorized javascript origin in Google OAuth 2.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, oauth-2.0, google-api, aws-lambda

I have managed to get user OAuth 2.0 access and refresh token on the PHP backend but when I send those tokens to the lambda function they work until the access token is expired. Once the access token is expired, the Google API javascript library tries to fetch new access token from the refresh token and fails because it is not authorized in the javascript origins in Google Developer console. I have no idea what should I put in the authorized javascript origins to allow AWS Lambda Function. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using AWS Cognito to set up a user pool: go to your user pool in the AWS console. Go to APP Integration and create a cognito domain. It will generate a URL for the Cognito domain. Put this in the authorized javascript origins on the Google console.

See the documentation from AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-google-social-identity-provider/